# Is there an easy way to query by form in Access a with MySQL backend?

Tags: mysql, vba, forms, ms-access

I'm creating an Access form frontend for a MySQL database backend, which is going to replace a preexisting alpha five backend & frontend.

The Alpha Five database has built-in functionality to query-by-form, which works as follows: Say the user is in the Contacts form, and they want to search for a contact. They select an option dropdown to enable Query-by-form mode, wherein every field becomes blank. The user then types in their search terms in any and all fields they wish to search by, and presses the search button. This runs the query to the database. In Alpha the results are shown in datasheet form, where the user can then select their desired result to open it in the main form.

Basically, I want to replicate this in Access. I've already got a fully-functioning Contacts entry form, which looks like so:

[image]

I've got a rough idea of what I need to do, which is to have a command button that will run an SQL query through VBA based on the current values in the fields, then set that query as the recordsource, a technique I learned from this resource: http://msofficeshare.com/Access-Search-Form/

I tested the method in the above link on just a few fields, and managed to slim down the VBA by having the event triggered at the press of a button, and not redundantly performed after each field is updated. But still, writing the VBA and SQL query would prove to take a not insignificant amount of time and hassle, as by my count there are upwards of 25 searchable fields in my form. The second problem I face is that Access immediately pushes updates to fields as they are typed in. This means that if the user were to begin typing a name to search while on a form, it would obviously edit the record. The solution that comes to mind immediately is to skip to a new form, but that would create a new record that's only the search term.

In summary, my question is twofold:

1) Is there an easy way to search by fields in a form in Access, or should I just write a protracted SQL query in VBA?
2) Is there a way to enter "search mode" wherein all fields are cleared and do not create a new record, or should I painstakingly recreate my whole contacts form, but with unbound fields for searching?

Thank you for taking the time to read!

Comment: 1) Access has 'filter by form' functionality. 2) Isn't that what 'filter by form' does? For custom search form review http://allenbrowne.com/ser-62.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@June7 solved my problem: Just use the built-in filter by form functionality! As usual, I was making things more complicated than they need to be.